# How do I query count of 2 fields occurences in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a PlayTrack model like this, each time a `user` plays a `track`, it means 1 record in `PlayTrack`

```
class PlayTrack(models.Model):
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='default_token')
```

So, how do I query the play count of each user ?

I've tried `PlayTrack.objects.annotate(Count('user'), Count('track')).values('user', 'track__count')`, but it gives me something like

```
<QuerySet [{'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, {'user': 2, 'track__count': 1}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

What I need is something like

```
{'user': 2, 'track__count': 3},{'user': 3, 'track__count': 5},{'user': 4, 'track__count': 10},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models import Count

PlayTrack.objects.values('user').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

This is similar to **`SELECT user,COUNT(id) from PlayTrack GROUP BY user`** SQL query.By this query you'll get *all PlayTrack information grouped by user*

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have a second thought, `track__count` is taking the count of `track`. So I assume you need to get the result as **`SELECT user,COUNT(track) from PlayTrack GROUP BY user`**, which could possible by,

```
from django.db.models import Count

PlayTrack.objects.values('user').annotate(count=Count('track'))
```